# Visual Studio 2010 64 bit setup registry issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, registry, 64-bit, setup-project

I've Visual Studio 2010 on a Vista 64bit.
I've created a setup project, with x64 target.
I've added two Launch Condition :

1. Search on Registry Key `"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1F1C2DFC-2D24-3E06-BCB8-725134ADF989}"`
   Try to find Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable **x86**.
2. Search on Registry Key `"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE}"` Try to finMicrosoft Visual C++
       2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable
       **x64**.

The installer find the first key, but not the second! I suppose that the OS **redirects the installer under the Wow6432Node**! Why if the target is x64 ? How can an installer looks in the "64bit registry zone" ?

Thank you.
Salvo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by Visual Studio setup projects. However, you can try this:

- after building the project open the MSI with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- go to [RegLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table and find the 64-bit search
- in "Type" column change the value to **18**
- save the changes

This way the registry search should use the 64-bit hive.

Comment: Yes! it works!
And viceversa ? if the setup starts at 64bit (without the bootstrap setup.exe) it doesn't see the wow6432node but always looks in the 64bit zone, in this case?

Comment: In a 64-bit installer use the normal registry path (without Wow6432Node in it) and make sure that the Type column is set to 2 (it doesn't search the 64-bit hive).

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Connect issue with a workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/110105/launch-conditions-for-x64-deployment-project-use-wow6432node#details) to automate the answer given by Cosmin Pirvu. It uses JScript in a post-build step to make the edit to the MSI file.